Why am I not connecting to Adafruit.IO
I am using ArduinoIDE on a MacBook Pro running MACOS 15.1 to install this program on an ESP32-Cam AI Thinker.
The program connects to my wifi using my ssid and password but it does not connect to my Adafruit.IO account with the credentials supplied.  I know the credentials are good because I took them from my account and I have connected to Adafruit with them with other programs.  I am trying to create a small simple program to use for another problem I have.
I got this to work by using AutoConnect.h to input and store my ssid and password instead of hard coding it. Now everything works fine.  I will move on to the other problem in another post.
Here is the working code.
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"
#include "Arduino.h"       
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define AIO_SERVER      "io.adafruit.com"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT  1883       // 8883 for MQTTS
#define AIO_USERNAME   "XXXXXX"     //original

#define AIO_KEY    "keykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykeykey"

#define MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE 18000000
long debouncing_time = 1000;
volatile unsigned long wifiResetLastMillis = 0;
bool shouldSaveConfig = false;


 WiFiManager wifiManager;
   // wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(600);

WiFiClient client;
void saveConfigCallback () {
  Serial.println("Should save config");
  shouldSaveConfig = true;}

 

  
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);

Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe video2 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt,AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/video");

Adafruit_MQTT_Publish wifi = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt,AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/wifi-connection");
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish camera2 = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME"/feeds/camera");

    

void MQTT_connect() {

 int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
    mqtt.disconnect();
     Serial.print("disconnect");
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  uint8_t retries = 30;
  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
       Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
       Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
       mqtt.disconnect();
       delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
       retries--;
       if (retries == 0) {
         // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
         while (1);
       }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");

  }



void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);
   
    wifiManager.autoConnect("LEVEL2");
   Serial.println("Connected"); 
 

 
delay(2000);
  }

 
void loop() {

 
if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {  Serial.println("Connected3");
delay(1000);


  MQTT_connect();
delay(500);
 }

}

I hope this helps someone else.

I figured out that the WiFi wasn't really connecting so the MQTT couldn't connect.  I changed my code to use AutoConnect to input and save my ssid and password.  The program then connected to the WiFi and the MQTT connected.  I will change my code above to show what I finally did.
